# Context Action Menu not getting hide in Ionic (Android)

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

On long press gesture the context action menu appears along the selected text.
But not getting hide unless I select an option from the menu.

First to enable context action menu, I used this:

```
overflow-scroll = "true" in the ion-content.
```

In the CSS class, I wrote:

```
-webkit-user-select: auto;
```

But now I can't hide it. It is locked on my view. Even after touching anywhere in my web view, it is still enabled. To hide context menu I used this:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
-webkit-touch-callout:none;
```

But still not getting success. This particular issue is in android only. For iOS, it is working fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Ionic version - 2.1.0

Update

Finally I found the answer.

I used the following two methods. First method to select text on long press and second method to remove selection.

```
           /*----------- To get selection--------*/

           $scope.getSelectionText = function() {
           var text = "";
           if (window.getSelection) {
              text = window.getSelection().toString();
              $scope.selectMode = true;
           } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
              text = document.selection.createRange().text;
              $scope.selectMode = true;
           }

            return text;
        };

        /*---------------To remove selection----------*/

           $scope.remove = function(){
           if (window.getSelection) {
               if (window.getSelection().empty) {  // Chrome
                  window.getSelection().empty();
               } else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) {  // Firefox
                 window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
               }
           } else if (document.selection) {  // IE?
                 document.selection.empty();
           }
          };
```

And add ng-click to your div

```
         <div class="selectable" ng-click="remove()">
               <ng-include src="activeTab.url"></ng-include>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.

I used the following two methods. First method to select text on long press and second method to remove selection.

```
               /*----------- To get selection--------*/

               $scope.getSelectionText = function() {
               var text = "";
               if (window.getSelection) {
                  text = window.getSelection().toString();
                  $scope.selectMode = true;
               } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
                  text = document.selection.createRange().text;
                  $scope.selectMode = true;
               }

                return text;
            };

            /*---------------To remove selection----------*/

               $scope.remove = function(){
               if (window.getSelection) {
                   if (window.getSelection().empty) {  // Chrome
                      window.getSelection().empty();
                   } else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) {  // Firefox
                     window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
                   }
               } else if (document.selection) {  // IE?
                     document.selection.empty();
               }
              };
```

And add ng-click to your div

```
             <div class="selectable" ng-click="remove()">
                   <ng-include src="activeTab.url"></ng-include>
             </div>
```